# Highlight cells in CollectionView

Tags: ios, highlight, cells, collectionview

I'm building an app in iOS and I want the Cells in my CollectionView to highlight when touched, pretty much like the normal buttons. How can I achieve this in the **didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** method?

Comment: Change the background color of that cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    .....
    if (cell.selected) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1]; // highlight selection
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Default color
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1]; //     //cell.lblImgTitle.text = @"xxx";
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: I solved it by changing the Alpha of the picture in the cell in the didHighlightItemAtIndexPath and didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath methods. Anyway, I'll set your answer as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you post how did you solve your issue in the answer? It will be helpful for others ...diogo-appdev

Answer (score 5):

If you subclassed the cell class, put this in your .m file

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if(selected)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.5];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

why can not change the background color through the cocoa pods?I new a user-defined collectionView cell class`

```
   - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        CHSMenuControlCell *cell = (CHSMenuControlCell*)[collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1]; //     //cell.lblImgTitle.text = @"xxx";
    }

    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CHSMenuControlCell *cell = (CHSMenuControlCell *)[collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```